# What do you call the phenomenon where you suddenly feel that a word's spelling is wrong?

Tags: orthography

First of all, does this actually happen to others? Hopefully it does.

In my case at least, the most commonplace words suddenly seem to be spelled wrong.

The most common examples are **why**, **while**, **when** etc. I develop this sudden feeling that the word **why** is in fact spelled wrong.

Is this a thing? Please point out if the question is off topic though.

Comment: [Dilbert's view](http://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=webster)

Comment: Haha. Could you post it as an answer though? Don't like leaving it marked as unanswered

Comment: No, this doesn't really happen to me. My sense for misspelled words is almost unerring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an editor, it happens to me all the time. Every time an author writes "seperate," for instance, I doubt my own knowledge that it should be "separate." I double-check the spelling of common words all the time when I'm editing. My advice is never become an editor -- it slows your reading, makes writing nearly impossible, and has few rewards.

All credit for the following goes to @TimLymington:

http://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=webster

Comment: Heck, "separate" is easy.  I still remember the story in my "reader" from about the 5th grade, and so I look for "a rat".

Comment: @HotLicks -- Hahahaha! As I tell my wife, "That was probably before my time." :--))

Comment: @HotLicks Tom Hastings and the Blacksmith?

Comment: @Conrado - Yeah, Hastings Mills.  Apparently Mabel O'Donnell was the author.